# Matplotlib fuzzy near 0

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

[image]

Hi all, two questions:

First: Can anyone tell me what that fuzzy scrible near the 0 on the x and y axis is and how to remove it?

Second: I know that rects1 output ['42', '12', '167', '80', '197', '210', '41'] why is it showing 0,1,2,3,4,5,6? what am i missing?

```
        ylst = []
        xlst = []
        xlst1 = []

        figure = Figure(figsize=(9, 6), dpi=180)

        for xgrp in get_days_week(3):
            xlst.append(media_dia(xgrp).get("totmedia<1h", "ERRO"))
            xlst1.append(tempo_dia(xgrp).get("tot_viag", "ERRO"))
            ylst.append(str(xgrp))

        x = np.arange(len(ylst))  # the label locations
        y = np.arange(len(xlst1))
        width = 0.25  # the width of the bars

        figure, ax = plt.subplots()
        rects1 = ax.bar(x - width / 2, xlst, width, label="N veiculos com media viagem < 1h")
        rects2 = ax.bar(x + width / 2, xlst1, width, label="Total Viagens")

        figure.set_figheight(6)
        figure.set_figwidth(8)

        ax.set_title(titulo)
        ax.legend()
        ax.set_xlabel(xname)
        #ax.set_ylabel(yname)
        ax.bar_label(rects1, padding=3)
        ax.bar_label(rects2, padding=3)

        ax.set_xticks(x)
        ax.set_xticklabels(ylst)

       # ax.set_yticks(y)
       # ax.set_yticklabels(xlst1)

        print("::: ",y)
        print("-> ",xlst1)

        # ax.set_yticklabels(np.arange(200))



        figure.tight_layout()
        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(figure, graphframe)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=1, column=col)
```

Im sorry for the two questions but since its the same code and are problably connected i hope its alright.

Comment: thanks, its better but it still show some line right above the 0

Comment: ax1.set_yticklabels(labels=[]) would get rid of your y labels. Also, tight layout can sometimes mess up your figures especially if you have given explicit commands on its height and width. remember tight figure layout affect those as well.

Comment: removed the #figure.tight_layout() and width and height specifications but it didnt change anything

Comment: The problem is that `xlst1` are strings instead of numbers.  You need to convert them to numbers, e.g. `xlst1.append(float(tempo_dia(xgrp).get("tot_viag", "ERRO")))`. When they are strings, they can't be plot together with `xlst` which contains numbers.

Comment: it work :) thanks you soo much :)